# OPENVPN: Problem for setup a VPN supporting IPv6 on linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, openvpn, vpn

I have a problem for setup my VPN on OrangePi(This is a micro-computer same as Raspberry Pi)

My project is to configure a VPN with ipv6 on him. So, i have find a project on github, which proposes to automate the creation of this:

> https://github.com/xl-tech/OpenVPN-easy-setup (By ***xl-tech***)

Before testing it on my OrangePi, I tried to start this script under my VM running on `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64Bits`, and it works fine.
However, when I go on my OrangePi, it does not work.

After browsing the error messages displayed (related to the fact that the iptables firewall is not setup I guess), I can not find the cause that would prevent it from really working ...

I still have a lot to learn, it's been a few hours that I block and I can not find why this don't work..

My OrangePi runs on `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS(GNU/Linux 3.4.39 armv7l)`.

Can you guide me to the right path? :(

Here is the return of this script on my OrangePi:

```
root@OrangePI:~/OpenVPN-easy-setup# bash openvpnsetup.sh
TUN/TAP is enabled
IPv4 forwarding is already enabled
NAME="Ubuntu"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package netfilter-persistent
Firewall stopped and disabled on system startup
awk: line 0: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)
[       ]+|
Select server IP to listen on (only used for IPv4):
1) Internal IP - 192.168.1.11 25.33.106.84 2620:9b::1921:6a54  (in case you are behind NAT)
2) External IP - 90.51.33.97

2
Select server PORT to listen on:
1) tcp 443 (recommended)
2) udp 1194 (default)
3) Enter manually (proto (lowercase!) port)

2
Select server cipher:
1) AES-256-GCM (default for OpenVPN 2.4.x, not supported by Ubuntu Server 16.x)
2) AES-256-CBC
3) AES-128-CBC (default for OpenVPN 2.3.x)
4) BF-CBC (insecure)

2
Enable IPv6? (ensure that your machine have IPv6 support):
1) Yes
2) No

1
Check your selection
Server will listen on 90.51.33.97
Server will listen on udp 1194
Server will use AES-256-CBC cipher
IPv6 - 1 (1 is enabled, 0 is disabled)
Press enter to continue...
NAME="Ubuntu"
Using CA Common Name: Fort-Funston CA
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
....................................+++
...+++
writing new private key to 'ca.key'
-----
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
............+++
....+++
writing new private key to 'server-cert.key'
-----
Using configuration from /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows
countryName           :PRINTABLE:'US'
stateOrProvinceName   :PRINTABLE:'CA'
localityName          :PRINTABLE:'SanFrancisco'
organizationName      :PRINTABLE:'Fort-Funston'
organizationalUnitName:PRINTABLE:'MyVPN'
commonName            :PRINTABLE:'server-cert'
name                  :PRINTABLE:'EasyRSA'
emailAddress          :IA5STRING:'my@vpn.net'
Certificate is to be certified until Sep 21 10:09:07 2023 GMT (1825 days)

Write out database with 1 new entries
Data Base Updated
Generating DH parameters, 2048 bit long safe prime, generator 2
This is going to take a long time
.........+..................................+................................................................................................+..........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................+.................................+....................................................................................................................................................+....+..................................................................................................................................................................................................+.................................................+.........................................+...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................+.................................................................................................+................................................................................................+...........................................................................................................................................+....+....................................................................................+...........................................................................................................................................................................++*++*
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
...........+++
..+++
writing new private key to 'revoked.key'
-----
Using configuration from /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows
countryName           :PRINTABLE:'US'
stateOrProvinceName   :PRINTABLE:'CA'
localityName          :PRINTABLE:'SanFrancisco'
organizationName      :PRINTABLE:'Fort-Funston'
organizationalUnitName:PRINTABLE:'MyVPN'
commonName            :PRINTABLE:'revoked'
name                  :PRINTABLE:'EasyRSA'
emailAddress          :IA5STRING:'my@vpn.net'
Certificate is to be certified until Sep 21 10:17:42 2023 GMT (1825 days)

Write out database with 1 new entries
Data Base Updated
Using configuration from /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
Revoking Certificate 01.
Data Base Updated
Using configuration from /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
revoked.crt: C = US, ST = CA, L = SanFrancisco, O = Fort-Funston, OU = MyVPN, CN = revoked, name = EasyRSA, emailAddress = my@vpn.net
error 23 at 0 depth lookup:certificate revoked
Error 23 indicates that revoke is successful
IPv6 forwarding is already enabled
OpenVPN 2.3.2 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
NAME="Ubuntu"
openvpnsetup.sh: line 360: systemctl: command not found
openvpnsetup.sh: line 360: systemctl: command not found
openvpnsetup.sh: line 361: systemctl: command not found
openvpnsetup.sh: line 361: systemctl: command not found
openvpnsetup.sh: line 362: systemctl: command not found
Setup is complete. Happy VPNing!
Use /etc/openvpn/newclient.sh to generate client config
```

So:

```
root@OrangePI:~/OpenVPN-easy-setup# /etc/openvpn/newclient.sh try
Script to generate unified config for Windows App
sage: newclient.sh <common-name>
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
.......................................+++
...............................................................................................................................+++
writing new private key to 'try.key'
-----
Using configuration from /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows
countryName           :PRINTABLE:'US'
stateOrProvinceName   :PRINTABLE:'CA'
localityName          :PRINTABLE:'SanFrancisco'
organizationName      :PRINTABLE:'Fort-Funston'
organizationalUnitName:PRINTABLE:'MyVPN'
commonName            :PRINTABLE:'try'
name                  :PRINTABLE:'EasyRSA'
emailAddress          :IA5STRING:'my@vpn.net'
Certificate is to be certified until Sep 21 10:56:28 2023 GMT (1825 days)

Write out database with 1 new entries
Data Base Updated
OpenVPN 2.3.2 arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [eurephia] [MH] [IPv6] built on Jun 22 2017
COMPLETE! Copy the new unified config from here: /etc/openvpn/bundles/try.ovpn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting error messages as the script is not finding the `systemctl` command:

```
openvpnsetup.sh: line 360: systemctl: command not found
```

The missing command is used to control `systemd`, the cutting-edge (sometimes bleeding-edge) `init` subsystem.

According to [this old Ubuntu wiki page,](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/systemd) the earliest possible version `systemd` was introduced in Ubuntu was 14.10 or more likely 15.04. You are running 14.04.5 which is *older* than either of those. Before `systemd`, I think Ubuntu used to use `upstart` as its `init` subsystem.

A transition from one type of `init` subsystem to another type is a pretty major change: it affects how system startup and shutdown are performed, and how system services are defined and controlled. With `systemd`, the `systemctl` command is the universal tool for most service management tasks.

You should now read lines #360, #361 and #362 in the `openvpnsetup.sh` script, find out what the `systemctl` commands on those lines are attempting to do, and replace them with the corresponding commands that are applicable to the `upstart` init subsystem. Very likely you'll also have to look for any files dropped into `/etc/systemd/system`, and replace them with `upstart`-style service definitions.

From your github link, those lines are:

```
systemctl enable netfilter-persistent & systemctl start netfilter-persistent
systemctl enable openvpn@server & systemctl start openvpn@server
systemctl restart netfilter-persistent
```

i.e. enable `netfilter-persistent` and openVPN server services to start automatically at boot & start them immediately, and then restart the `netfilter-persistent` service one more time, probably to ensure that any changes to firewall rules that might have been made by the OpenVPN startup are immediately stored persistently.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand better why it happened to me.
So I just added these lines:

`/etc/init.d/openvpn restart`, `service openvpn restart`
'
Indeed, `netfilter-persistent` seems poorly implemented ... I will try to better understand this :)
Thanks again for this message